# Is it possible to rotate video chunks in javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, chunks, mediadevices, picture-in-picture

I am trying to rotate video tag and put it in "picture in picture" mode,

I know we can rotate video using transform: rotateY(180deg), but css would not be applied to video in "pip" mode.

So i think if we can rotate its chunks and then call it in "pip" mode

Here is the code, any suggestions please...

```
const cameraRecording = async function(micStatus){
    try{
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video : true, 
            audio: micStatus ? false : true
        });
        cameraRecElem.srcObject = stream;
        record(stream, true);
    }
    catch(err){
        showError('Error accessing camera or microphone');
    }
};
```

```
const record = function(stream, pipStatus, stream2){

    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    recorder.addEventListener('start', (e) =>{
        chunks = [];
        if(pipStatus) cameraRecElem.requestPictureInPicture() && (cameraRecElem.style.opacity="0");
    });

    recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (e) =>{
        chunks.push(e.data);
    });

    recorder.addEventListener('stop', (e) =>{
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        if(stream2) stream2.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        clearInterval(counting);
        setLink(chunks);
        if(pipStatus) document.exitPictureInPicture();
    });

    startCountDown();
    recorder.start();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To do so, we need to go through an HTML canvas element, do the mirroring there and use a stream captured from this canvas.

The new [VideoCodecs](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/) and [MediaStream Insertable](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-transform) APIs help a lot in the process of grabbing the frame from the MediaStream in a performant way, but unfortunately there's apparently no easy way to mirror the frame and produce a new MediaStream without drawing said frame on a canvas.

For the browsers that don't support the WebCodecs API, we have to go through an HTML video element, which will play the MediaStream and draw that video element on the canvas.

Here is what I believe is the most performant way of doing this:

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = (evt) => {
  evt.currentTarget.remove();
  const stream = getCanvasStream();
  const mirrored = mirrorStream(stream);
  document.querySelector("video.default").srcObject = stream;
  document.querySelector("video.mirrored").srcObject = mirrored;
};

function mirrorStream(stream) {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  Object.assign(canvas, { width: 0, height: 0 });
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
  const drawOnCanvas = (image, width, height) => {
    // MediaStream's video size may change over time
    if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      ctx.setTransform(-1, 0, 0, 1, width, 0);
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  };
  // the MediaStreamTrackProcessor API is available, we use it
  if (window.MediaStreamTrackProcessor) {
    const processor = new MediaStreamTrackProcessor(track);
    const reader = processor.readable.getReader();
    reader.read().then(function readChunk({ done, value }) {
      const { displayWidth, displayHeight } = value;
      drawOnCanvas(value, displayWidth, displayHeight);
      value.close(); // close the VideoFrame when we're done with it
      if (!done) {
        reader.read().then(readChunk);
      }
    });
  } else {
    const vid = document.createElement("video");
    vid.srcObject = stream;
    // in case requestVideoFrameCallback is available, we use it
    // otherwise we fallback on rAF
    const scheduler = vid.requestVideoFrameCallback ?
        (cb) => vid.requestVideoFrameCallback(cb) : requestAnimationFrame;
    const draw = () => {
      const { videoWidth, videoHeight } = vid;
      drawOnCanvas(vid, videoWidth, videoHeight);
      scheduler(draw);
    };
    vid.play().then(draw);
  }
  return canvas.captureStream();
}

// StackSnippet only:
// because StackSnippet don't allow the use of gUM
// we return a MediaStream from a simple <canvas> anim
function getCanvasStream() {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "30px sans-serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  function anim() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0], canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
  anim();
  return canvas.captureStream();
}
```

```css
video { width: calc(50vw - 10px); border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<button>begin</button><br>
<video autoplay controls class="default">
</video><video autoplay controls class="mirrored">
</video>
```

And as a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zox6qn1w/) using `getUserMedia()`.

---

Note that if you did want to vertically mirror the video, then we could have done so without a canvas, by using `createImageBitmap(VideoFrame, { imageOrientation: "flipY" })` and a [MediaStreamTrackGenerator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrackGenerator), but there is no way to do horizontal mirroring this way.